# Extract each value from an associative array with unknown length and value names

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [item1] => value1
    [item2] => value
    [item3] => value3
)
```

And I want to extract all the names and values to variables.
But say, I don't know the names of items that the array contains.
I wanna generate variables for each array item with the name of this item name in array to make possible of using this variables later.
The result should look like this:

```
item_name1 = item_value1
item_name2 = item_value2
item_name3 = item_value3
```

Seems the foreach loop should be usefull here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood this.

If you want the key from the array to become a variable with the same name you can use the extract function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 1):

Using built-in functions is always faster, but if you need the foreach approach with $$:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$val)
{
    $$key = $val;
}
```

Comment: Now $$key becomes array... I need to key is tha variable name, and val is the variable value

Comment: $$key will create a variable with a name the value of $key and value $val. If $val is another array then $$key will become an array named the value of $key. It depends on what you pass.